# Java is unavailable for Opencv installation

Tags: java, opencv, cmake, alpine-linux

Hi I am using an alpine image to install opencv for Java, but I get that java is unavailable to be built:

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine3.9

ENV ANT_VERSION 1.10.5-r0
ENV ANT_HOME /usr/share/java/apache-ant
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV JAVA_APPEND_LIBRARY_DIRECTORIES ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/amd64
ENV JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${JAVA_HOME}/include

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base cmake ccache apache-ant=${ANT_VERSION} pkgconfig

ADD opencv-4.0.1 /tmp/opencv-4.0.1

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/opencv-4.0.1/build

WORKDIR /tmp/opencv-4.0.1/build

RUN cmake -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
```

I verified from the container that all envs point to the correct folders and that the folders exist.

The Cmake command shows:

```html
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "2.7")
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "3.2")
-- Looking for ccache - found (/usr/bin/ccache)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
...
-- Found apache ant: /usr/bin/ant (1.10.5)
-- Found JNI: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
...
-- General configuration for OpenCV 4.0.1 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
--
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2019-05-12T15:35:59Z
--     Host:                        Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.13.0
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
--
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
--       requested:                 SSE3
--     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       SSE4_1 (7 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
--       SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
--       FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
--       AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
--       AVX2 (13 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
--       AVX512_SKX (1 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_SKX
--
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 8.3.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     ccache:                      YES
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          ade dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:       ittnotify libprotobuf zlib libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf quirc ippiw ippicv
--
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator ml objdetect photo python_bindings_generator stitching ts video videoio
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 java js python2 python3
--     Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
--
--   GUI:
--     GTK+:                        NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 1.5.3-62)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.35)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.9)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
--
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      NO
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       avcodec:                   NO
--       avformat:                  NO
--       avutil:                    NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     v4l/v4l2:                    NO
--
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
--
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Intel IPP:                   2019.0.0 Gold [2019.0.0]
--            at:                   /tmp/opencv-4.0.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
--     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2019.0.0)
--               at:                /tmp/opencv-4.0.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       NO
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
--
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /tmp/opencv-4.0.1/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
--
--   Python (for build):            NO
--
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.10.5)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/include
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
--
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/opencv-4.0.1/build
```

Comment: Can you provide an error trace? All I can find is that cmake can not find VTK. Are you sure Java is the problem?

Comment: There is no error trace since there is no error. Something is missing from the environment and that's why java is missing on the build targets.

Answer (score 2):

Finally , java appeared on the build targets when python2 was installed. I don't know why this happens. This was not mentioned on the java guides on how to build opencv for java.

the configuration after installing python changed to

```
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     ccache:                      YES
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          ade dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:       ittnotify libprotobuf zlib libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf quirc ippiw ippicv
--
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc java java_bindings_generator ml objdetect photo python_bindings_generator stitching ts video videoio
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 js python2 python3
--     Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
--
--   GUI:
--     GTK+:                        NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 1.5.3-62)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.35)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.9)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
--
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      NO
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       avcodec:                   NO
--       avformat:                  NO
--       avutil:                    NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     v4l/v4l2:                    NO
--
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
--
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Intel IPP:                   2019.0.0 Gold [2019.0.0]
--            at:                   /tmp/opencv-4.0.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
--     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2019.0.0)
--               at:                /tmp/opencv-4.0.1/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       NO
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
--
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /tmp/opencv-4.0.1/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
--
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
--
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.10.5)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/include
--     Java wrappers:               YES
--     Java tests:                  YES
--
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/opencv-4.0.1/build
```

Comment: I also might add that seemingly it needs ONLY Python2. I had Python 2 and 3 installed and I couldn't make it work until I uninstalled 3.